# como dividir cadenas en java

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

hola buenas quería hacerles una consulta, talvez alguien que sepa más me ayude, pasa que necesito cortar una cadena en trozos más pequeños, pero pasa que lo hago no porque necesite cortarlas sino porque necesito ver si están escritas correctamente.

la idea sería tener una cadena así

```
String cadena = "nombre1, apellido1, apellido2";
```

lo que yo necesito es que **no pase esto** cuando se escriban cadenas

```
String cadena = "nombre1 apellido1, apellido2";
```

ni esto

```
String cadena = "nombre1 apellido1 apellido2";
```

por lo que el usuario ingresa al archivo su nombre con sus datos, pero él debe dividirlos por coma para que Ami se me haga mas fácil hacer la division.

**Lo que pasa es que yo necesito detectar espacios entre cadenas que no tengan la ,**

lo que estaba intentando es algo como esto

```
                            String str = "nombre, apellido1, apellido2";
                            char ch = ',';
                            

                            int index = str.indexOf(ch);
                            
                            int sf = 0;
                            
                            while (index != -1) {
                                System.out.println(index);
                                
                                
                                index = str.indexOf(ch, index + 1);
                                
                                
                            }
```

lo que hago aquí es contar las comas que se encuentra, pero no me da la idea para hacer lo que les pregunto.

**porque la idea sería detectar que las cadenas están con coma para dividirlas, pero si existe un espacio sin coma entre dos cadenas Alli es el error que ocupo marcar.**

**ESTO MAS QUE TODO TIENE EL OBJETIVO DE SER UNA ALERTA DE ERROR.**

**ya que lo que estoy haciendo es un compilador**

que pasa si en java definimos variables

asi

**int variable1, variable2;**
esta correcto

y si ahora lo hacemos asi

**int variable1 variable2;**
esta malo porque en medio de las variables deben separarse

por lo que pueden pensar que es un problema no tiene sentido, pero no tiene sentido porque no pensaba mencionar que lo que estoy haciendo es un compilador. pero ya que me mencionan que lo que intento hacer no tiene sentido por eso ocupo hacer eso.

**por lo que cualquier sugerencia para detectar que no se escribieron comas entre cadenas lo agradezco mucho**

Comment: Si haces un `split` por `' '`(espacio), el último carácter de las cadenas va a ser una `,` (menos el último) creo que con eso podrías resolverlo

Comment: "pero él debe dividirlos por coma para que Ami se me haga mas fácil hacer la division." cuando leo cosas asi, pienso que estas resolviendo un problema que no tenias, aplicando una solucion que no corresponde. Que es lo que se te hace mas facil??? porque??? me parece, que tu problema es otro... que era lo complicado que no podias resolver???

Comment: me gusto ese dicho de pienso que estas resolviendo un problema que no tenias, aplicando una solucion que no corresponde.jejeej

Comment: lo que pasa @gbianchi es que el problema es más amplio, el código y el proyecto igual, lo que pasa es que cuando uno hace preguntas, intenta explicar las cosas lo más sencillas para que ustedes puedan entenderlas, entonces realmente si lo vez de esa forma es más que todo porque lo intente explicar yendo directo al error que intento resolver.

Comment: pero realmente ese código que intento hacer yo le tengo que agregar más cosas y hacer mucho más. ajjaj talvez por eso lo vez así

Comment: @LiulinContreras quieres detectar cuando existen espacios y las palabras no están separadas por comas, y tal vez sugerir al usuario como debería ser lo correcto?

Comment: @Jorgesys lo que estoy haciendo es un compilador

Comment: ya edite la pregunta

Comment: claro.. ahi esta el problema... estas haciendo un compilador.. y un compilador.. no se hace asi... Vos estas parseando lineas, cuando tenes que parsear tokens.. y luego, segun el token que tenes, seguir en un arbol de desicion, que tipo de token es el siguiente aceptado... lee sobre eso... cada una de tus palabras, es un token ;)...

Comment: @gbianchi si claro, ese fue el detalle que no dije que era un compilador.

y si yo tengo un dos while, uno que recorre con las líneas originales, y otro while que recorre con dividiendo las cadenas en tokens, entonces si te entiendo, pero según yo la validación saldría mejor respetando la cadena original y no dividirla. pero si gracias por el consejo

Comment: no.. si fuera asi, los compiladores trabajarian asi.. y por algo, no lo hacen ;).. las cadenas se miran token a token... el problema con tu metodo, es que mañana vas a venir con otro problema de parseo.. pasado mañana con otro.. y al dia siguiente otro mas.. y tu compilador va a tardar dias en procesar dos lineas ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String cadena = "pepe,antonio , marce juan";
String ca[] = cadena.split( "" );
String sal ="";
boolean primera = true;
for( int i = 0; i < ca.length; i++ ) {
     if( ca[ i ].matches( "[a-zA-Z]" )) {
        sal += ca[ i ];
           primera = true;
     }
     else {
        if( primera ) {
           sal += ",";
           primera = false;
        }
     }
  }
  System.out.println( sal );
```

Este sería un método "cavernícola"", que no por eso, deja de funcionar, seguro alguno de mis admirados colegas, va a presentar un *regex* que lo haga en una sola linea.

Comment: Fuee si pero muchas gracias, eso que hiciste me funciona de maravilla para lo que necesito, muchas gracias mas bien

Comment: Un placer maestro!!.